Cannot get Azure subscriptions using `msal` and requests in python through REST API
I can get subsriptions using token captured from browser:

Then I switch to Python and msal.
I use the following code:
import msal
import requests
import sys
import json

data = json.load(open("parameters.json"))

config = {
    "authority": f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{data['tenant']}",
    "client_id": data["client_id"],
    "client_secret": data["client_secret"],
    "scopes": [
        "https://management.azure.com/.default",
    ]
}

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    data["client_id"],
    authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{data['tenant']}",
    client_credential=data["client_secret"],
)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=[
        "https://management.azure.com/.default",
    ])


if "access_token" in result:
    print("success")
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))
    sys.exit(-1)

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {result['access_token']}"
}

response = requests.get(
    headers=headers, url="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2019-08-01")

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.content)
else:
    print(response.status_code)


However, I cannot get desired result:
success
b'{"value":[],"count":{"type":"Total","value":0}}'

The permissions are already granted:

I tried to add "https://management.azure.com//user_impersonation" to scope, but it fails with error:
AADSTS1002012: The provided value for scope https://management.azure.com//user_impersonation is not valid. Client credential flows must have a scope value with /.default suffixed to the resource identifier (application ID URI).

I reads about the "OBO" flow, but my app isn't supposed to need user interactions.
Ask:
Does I miss something in the auth flow or permissions?

Did you assign any RBAC roles to that application under the management group?

No and I don't know that. Can you give me a link?

Go to Azure Portal -> Search for 'Management groups' -> Select Management Group-> Access control(IAM) https://i.imgur.com/G81aa9H.png

You need to assign at least Reader role to the application under management group or subscriptions before running REST API.

I've created a management group since I don't have permission for the root group. Then I moved my subscription to that group. However, I don't see my application in the IAM role assignment page.  https://imgur.com/a/aFuvtCA

There is no need to create new management group. You can just assign Reader role to the application under the subscription. Check in what tenant or directory the application is present and switch to that directory.

I only have one directory and I've checked again that it's the current directory. I also tried to enter client ID but it also fails.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Also, I've gone through settings in the application page and there's no IAM there

You need to assign at least Reader role to the service principal before generating access token to call Azure Management API.
In my case, I registered one Microsoft Entra ID application and created one secret in it as below:

Now, I assigned Reader role to the service principal under the management group as below:

When I ran your code after assigning role to service principal, I got the response successfully like this:
import msal
import requests
import sys
import json

data = json.load(open("parameters.json"))

config = {
    "authority": f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{data['tenant']}",
    "client_id": data["client_id"],
    "client_secret": data["client_secret"],
    "scopes": [
        "https://management.azure.com/.default",
    ]
}

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    data["client_id"],
    authority=f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{data['tenant']}",
    client_credential=data["client_secret"],
)

result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=[
        "https://management.azure.com/.default",
    ])


if "access_token" in result:
    print("success")
else:
    print(result.get("error"))
    print(result.get("error_description"))
    print(result.get("correlation_id"))
    sys.exit(-1)

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {result['access_token']}"
}

response = requests.get(
    headers=headers, url="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2019-08-01")

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.content)
else:
    print(response.status_code)

Response:

